# not sure why I'm getting this routing error in Rails; do controller specs use routes.rb or just strings / symbols to methods?

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2

**Edit #2**

I'm writing a quick test suite for an api and am using controller specs. I am trying to use the routes for the post / get calls but are those even consulted or is it just symbols / strings to controllmer methods?

---

original question

This might be a really naive question but I have a named route in rails and am testing it with rspec. In routes.rb, I have:

```
match '/api/get-next-highest-position-in-menu-header' => 'api_edit#get_next_highest_position_in_menu_header', :as => :jt_next_highest
```

in my spec, I have the following:

```
post :jt_next_highest,  { menu_header_id: mh.id }
```

but I get the following error

```
1) ApiEditController Adding a Item should get the next highest position in a menu_header
 Failure/Error: post :jt_next_highest,  { menu_header_id: mh.id }
 AbstractController::ActionNotFound:
   The action 'jt_next_highest' could not be found for ApiEditController
 # ./spec/controllers/api_edit_controller_spec.rb:52:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

If I look at rake routes:

```
Fri May 17$ rake routes | grep 'get_next_highest' 
                 jt_next_highest        /arc/v1/api/get-next-highest-position-in-menu-header(.:format)                   api_edit#get_next_highest_position_in_menu_header
Fri May 17$
```

I'm not sure what is wrong with this as I feel that this should work. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

**edit 1**

trying:

```
post :jt_next_highest_path,  { menu_header_id: mh.id }
```

just got me

```
   The action 'jt_next_highest_path' could not be found for ApiEditController
```

Comment: now I'm just getting the error: `The action 'jt_next_highest_path' could not be found for ApiEditController`. I know I'm doing something so stupid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller specs bypass routing entirely, so when you do

```
post :foo
```

in a controller spec, `:foo` must be the action name, ie the name of the method in the controller. Which routes map onto that doesn't matter (as long as there is at least one).

Comment: thx, all makes sense now. I'm using these specs for testing a json api. Is that appropriate or do you feel there is a better way? Sorry for asking new question but would really appreciate your advice. I chose using controller specs because that is what http://meta.discourse.org uses for testing their api.